# How do I use private variables in a cross-package struct within a nested struct?

Tags: go

I created a Base structure that looks like a base class.

```golang
// package network

type Base struct {
    onReceive func(data []byte)    // <-- here
    onDestroy func()
    Rate      *RateRecoder
    Exit      chan struct{}
}
```

Then I implemented tcp, tls, udp and other specific structures on the basis of Base structure.

```golang
// package tcp

type TCP struct {
    network.Base    // <-- here
    Host string
    Port uint16
    conn net.Conn
}
```

I know that cross-package variables in Go need to be capitalized to represent public, but some variables in Base structure, such as onReceive, are best kept private in TCP structure.

Also, due to tcp, tls, udp, etc structures of protocols, I can't put the Base structure and TCP structures in the same package.

Capitalize all the variables in the Base structure, and the code works fine. But some variables in TCP structure need to be kept private. And that's my question.

How to solve my question. Thank you!

Comment: If you need to use some of the variables in the base struct from other packages, then they cannot be private.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the fields in `Base` private they must remain private.  If that breaks code that needs to access those fields then `Base` needs to provide some means by which they *can* be accessed.

#### In General...

You can add exported functions to `Base` that will return the values of any private fields that need to be read from outside the package.

If you need to be able to modify those variables, then you will need to additionally provide exported functions that modify them.  But, if that's the case, you may be better off simply exporting the fields directly.

Which of these approaches is the most appropriate in your case is hard to say without reviewing your approach more completely.

#### To Be Specific...

The one example you provided was a field holding a reference to a function, suggesting that what you need to be able to do is *call* that function from a struct containing `Base`.

For such cases, rather than exporting a function that returns the function reference, export a function to *call* that function:

```golang
func (b Base) OnReceive(data []byte) {
   b.onReceive(data)
}
```